# Set frequency of a specific post type from multiple custom posts in WordPress post query

Tags: php, wordpress

I am in a situation where i need to set occurrence of a specific post type in query, Let's assume my query as:

```
new WP_Query( [
   post_type => ['video','course','post']
] );
```

now in the loop i want the 'post' to come as every 3rd entry in the loop. e.g

1. video
2. course
3. post   <------ POST
4. video
5. course
6. post   < ------ POST

One way is to query 'post' separately and then rebuild the response with other post types. Besides this, is there a better approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much content you have in your database, it could be a tricky question.

A really simple solution would be to use CSS with flex:

When displaying items with flex, you can sepcify the order proprety :
https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css3_pr_order.php

So you need to use 3 variables for like so:

```
// Assume $items contains the list of contents resulting of your query
$items;

$order_video = 1;
$order_course = 2;
$order_post = 3;

?>
<div class="items_wrapper">
<?php
foreach($items as $item) {
    switch($item_post_type) {
        case  'video':
            $order = $order_video;
            $order_video += 3;
            break;
        case 'course':
            $order = $order_course;
            $order_course += 3;
            break;
        case 'post':
            $order = $order_post;
            $order_post += 3;
            break;
    }
    
    // display your item
    ?>
    <div class="item" style="order:<?php echo $order; ?>">
    ...
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
</div>
```

BUT keep in mind that this is ONLY a design trick, for indexation bots, your items will still be readed in the "code order".

If you have a lot of content I would separate each post type in his hown query (and cache it), then recompose the content in a unique array, then lopp through it.